# Sharepoint 2010 list column to not to allow special characters and white spaces

Tags: validation, js

I want to to some validation for  Sharepoint 2010 list column to not to allow special characters and white spaces.

Please let me know if any JS or Validation formula.

Answer (score 0):

To check special characters I think you need JS validation. To do that, just load or inject the following js function into your edit/new form .aspx

```
function PreSaveAction(){
    var format = /[ !@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]/;
    var fldName = 'Title';
    var fldType = 'Text'
    var ctrl = $('[id^='+fldName+'_][id$='+fldType+'Field]');
    if(ctrl && !format.test(ctrl.val())){
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

regards